# Trying to resolve an issue regarding ORDER BY in a query

Tags: php, mysql

I have created an *HTML table* filled in from a query and have set the query to order by in *descending order* however the query runs and the results show up in the table I cannot get the dates to run *descending*.

The database is correctly set up for a date field which is named as walk_date. I have also used `strtotime` to sort the date to human friendly.

> 05.10.2012
>   07.10.2012
>   18.08.2012
>   21.10.2012
>   22.09.2012

This is the order they come out in, and the following is my code:

```
<h1>A Photographic Diary</h1>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>

<div id="about-text">

<p>All walks are listed in order with the latest at the top. Walks can be filtered by area using the drop-down box. The abbreviated Area ID's are as follows:<br/>
YD  -   Yorkshire Dales<br/>
LD  -   Lake District<br/>
FB  -   Forest of Bowland<br/>
WPM -   West Pennine Moors<br/>
PD  -   Peak District<br/>
LOC -   Local<br/>
O   -   Other<br/></p>
</div>
 <!--Selects walk area -->
<br /> <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="walk_results.php">
<label>Area</label>
<select name="area_id">
<option value="">All</option>


<?php
$sql_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM walk GROUP BY area_id ORDER BY walk_date DESC");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
        echo "<option value='".$row["area_id"]."'".($row["area_id"]==$_REQUEST["area_id"]? " selected" : "").">".$row["area_id"]."</option>";
};

?>
<!-- Submits walk area -->
</select>
  </label>

  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" class="styled-button" value="Select Area" /></form> 
   <style type="text/css">
   .styled-button {
    -webkit-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0 1px 0 0;
    -moz-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0 1px 0 0;
    box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0 1px 0 0;
    border-bottom-color:#333;
    border:1px solid #6470ED;
    background-color:#6470ED;
    border-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    color:#fff;
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    text-shadow:#b2e2f5 0 1px 0;
    padding:2px
}


  </style>
</select>
  </label>  

<!-- Walk area results table -->
<div id= "result">
<br /><br />
<table width="900" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4">
  <tr>
    <td width="84" bgcolor="#6470ED" align="center"><strong>Select Walk</strong></td>
    <td width="75" bgcolor="#6470ED" align="center"><strong>Walk Date</strong></td>
    <td width="360" bgcolor="#6470ED" align="center"><strong>Title</strong></td>
    <td width="64" bgcolor="#6470ED" align="center"><strong>Distance (Miles)</strong></td>
    <td width="85" bgcolor="#6470ED" align="center"><strong>Ascent</strong></td>
    <td width="78" bgcolor="#6470ED" align="center"><strong>Time</strong></td>
    <td width="67" bgcolor="#6470ED" align="center"><strong>Area Id</strong></td>
  </tr>


<?php

if ($_REQUEST["area_id"]<>'') {
    $search_area_id = "AND area_id='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["area_id"])."'";
}

if ($_REQUEST["from"]<>'' and $_REQUEST["to"]<>''){

}

else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM walk  WHERE walk_id>\"\"".$search_string.$search_area_id ;

}

$sql_result= mysql_query ($sql) or die ('request"Error"'.$sql);
#echo "SQL $sql";  --- to view info ---

$clicked =$_REQUEST["area_id"];
$sql= "SELECT * FROM walk  WHERE area_id = '$clicked'";

if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result)>0) {

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
    $id = $row['walk_id'];
    $date_of_walk = $row['walk_date']; 
    $date_of_walk = date("d.m.Y", strtotime($date_of_walk));
#echo "id $id<br>";  --- to view info ---


?>  
<!-- Table Results -->
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo "<a href='walk_info.php?walk_id=$id'>Select Walk"?></a></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['walk_date']=$date_of_walk;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["title"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["distance"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["ascent"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["time"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["area_id"]; ?></td>
  </tr>

<?php
    }
} else {  

$row= mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result);$sql_result= mysql_query ($sql);
?>
<tr><td colspan="5">No results found.</td>
<?php   
 }
mysql_close()?>
```

Comment: If you stored your dates as the standard MySQL date format (YYYY-MM-DD) this would be simple to do with SQL.

Comment: Can you include the query you're trying to use/debug?

Comment: Is this actually a date/time column, or just a string? As John says, if it is a proper date type then it is trivial to sort it.

Comment: Wow You Guys are on the Case !!!!

Comment: Show the code!! Just edit the question and paste in the relevant bits.

Comment: The field has to be set as a string or the order by would work for sure. OP needs to change field to datetime or sort using php and date();

Comment: @spajce, re your edit: italics are really only for where spoken emphasis would occur in natural speech, or for terms that are so unusual they are highlighted (and are then usually subsequently defined).

Comment: Which type of field is walK_date defined as? Are you sure it is either date or datetime? And confirm when you are inserting these dates you insert them in the YYYY-MM-DD format..

Comment: Thanks edwardmp I have rechecked the DB and it is in the YYY-MM-DD format it is selected from the calender in myphpadmin as I input the data in all the required fields

Comment: @user1971485 - for code formatting, use backticks for inline code, but for blocks of code, indent by four spaces - or use the `{}` button, which does this for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you stored your dates as the standard MySQL date format (YYYY-MM-DD) this would be simple to do with SQL. Just use the `DESC` keyword in your `ORDER BY` clause with the `walk_date` field:

```
   SELECT *
     FROM table_name
 ORDER BY walk_date DESC
```

Comment: Thanks i have tried the usual and tried them again to see if i am stupid :-) I am sure it's my query

Answer (score 1):

Change use the `DESC` keyword in your query.

For example, if this was your query

```
Select someDate from someTable ORDER BY someDate
```

change it to

```
Select someDate from someTable ORDER BY someDate DESC
```

Edit: 
okay now you have shown your code. Here's how to apply the above to your exact query

```
SELECT * FROM walk WHERE walk_id ORDER BY walk_date={...} DESC
```

That's all there is to it.

Comment: Thanks  I have tried this I am sure its the queries i am running

Comment: Can someone help i have been trying to follow the inputting of code and marking it harmless but nothing it says seems to work i am sure having a dumb moment the script is php